# How to detect if ng-controller exists on a HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Im trying to write some fairly simple JS.

I have a rang of angular controllers defined on my HTML pages, e.g:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl1">

    // My code

</div>
```

How would i go about writing some vanilla JS/jQuery on page load, to detect if 'ng-controller' exists?

Thanks

Comment: Because, what i want to achieve is that if ng-controller exists, then angular.bootstrap(document,['myApp']);.... Not all my pages are/need to load Angular (not the best solution or correct use of ANgular i know)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple attribute [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector):

```
if(document.querySelector("[ng-controller]")) {
    // ng-controller tag exists
}
```